# Adding “required” text to an HTML form via CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a `<form>` that looks like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><span class="required"></span>
</form>
```

What I want to do is show some text, such as `*` or `Required` in the `<span>` element, instead of "hard coding" the text for every such place I need the text so the form looks something like this:

```
[input box] Required
```

I googled around and found that it could be done by a CSS style using `content` such as:

```
.required:before
{
  content: "aaaa"
}
```

But, should I be using this technique (is it supported in every major browser for example) or is there a more preferred way to do this sort of thing?

Thanks

**UPDATE** Ps. I don't want to use JavaScript for this, just plain CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that adding content using CSS is not right in most cases. However, visually highlighting a required field I find totally okay to do this way.

`content` is not supported widely enough (IE doesn't support it at all IIRC).

What you *could* do is have the "required" span contain a background image containing the "required" text or an asterisk. Using graphical text has some downsides, but none that a jQuery based solution wouldn't have either.

Comment: Pls see my comment @Pranay Rana above as well. If I use the "background-image" attribute, isn't it the same as the "content" attribute, with the only difference being that in case of "content" I add a string and with "background-image" I add a picture? Neither is "content", but both are adding some visually-presented "data", right?

Comment: @Zabba strictly speaking, yes. It is both not in sync with the philosophy of separating content and presentation. But if this works for you, though, taking into account all the downsides (graphical text is not readable in Screenreaders, doesn't get printed etc.) I tend to say it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Zabba: The difference is that `background-image` is widely supported.

Comment: Accepted; and I think @Mark in the comment of @Pranay Rana has a very good point too. In all, i think it's best to go with @Pekka's solution to use the CSS content attribute and then use JavaScript for the poor IE users :)

Comment: Adding a word to signify the type of something should not be considered content.  It gives no more information than putting the background red, if that happens to be your convention.  It's a stylistic choice, even if it happens to be letters.  It belongs in css.

Answer (score 6):

Check this :  [Content](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html)

aslo check this compatiblity
[image]

**Don't use**

I feel that we shouldn't use the content declaration at all. It adds content to the page, and CSS is meant for adding presentation to the page, and not content. Therefore I feel that you should use JavaScript if you want to dynamically generate content. CSS is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: microsoft strikes again... :(

Comment: But if CSS is meant for presentation only, what's the reason that CSS has the content attribute? I googled to W3C (http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/generate.html#propdef-content) and it says: "Generated content does not alter the document tree. In particular, it is not fed back to the document language processor (e.g., for reparsing)." So that means it is really "presentation" and not adding "content" to the page, right?

Comment: I don't think I buy into this argument that it shouldn't be used because it adds "content" to the page. Adding a little "required" blurb is no more content than a background image, or icon, or informative colors that CSS already conveys. It shouldn't be used to insert paragraphs, but for something like this, I think it's perfectly semantically suitable. That said... IE doesn't support it very well. What I would do is use the darn tag, then us JS to fix it only in the broken browsers.

Comment: @Mark: “Adding a little "required" blurb is no more content than a background image, or icon, or informative colors that CSS already conveys.” If CSS is the only way a user is being informed that the field is required, then it’s content, and shouldn’t be in the CSS.

Comment: @Paul: Maybe. But it's still not mission-critical. Presumably you have some kind of validation on the form. It's all just sprinkles.

Comment: @Mark: sure, but it’s a bit of a drag for a non-sighted user to fill out a form with no indication of which fields are required, and then get a bunch of validation messages telling them that oh sorry, those fields were required, we just didn’t tell you because we like putting stuff like that in the CSS alone. Basic usability for and good manners towards disabled users isn’t a sprinkle.

Comment: @Paul: Depends who your target audience is I guess. Screen-readers won't read the CSS-added content I guess? Oh well. I'm not really disagreeing with you, I think the best way is to do it with server-side programming if you can, but I'd say this is a low-priority feature, and if it saves you a few hours or as a stop-gap, this is a fine solution.

Comment: @Mark: in the UK, the Disability Discrimination Act makes non-sighted users a mandatory part of your target audience, and rightly so. I’d say not bothering to include form instructions in the content of a form is sloppy, negligent work. We’re not talking putting a man on the moon, we’re talking putting instructions on a form via HTML rather than CSS. There’s no excuse for not doing this properly.

Comment: That's an interesting law... I don't really think it's discriminatory..  it's not like we have anything against people with disabilities and of course everyone wants a wider audience... it's just laziness or time/budget reasons. Anyway, I think we've beat this to death.

Answer (score 2):

u can use jQuery for this thing.

jQuery is a javascript library:

write in header this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(span[class=required]).innerText='<sometext>';
});
```

but u must download this plugin. but u can use javascript too

Comment: This is a perfectly fine solution, even with a code example.: +1. Consider using "you" instead of "u" though, it will make your writing style look more mature

Comment: Did not work for me (syntax error).  One way I could get it to work was:

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span.required').text('*');
});

Answer (score 2):

Definitely shouldn't be using CSS to do that! God no! :p

As said above use javascript - but if you want to avoid that then you have to use Server Side Scripting - So get learning some PHP.

Comment: I disagree in this specific case: Starting to use a server side language to build a form is much more kludgy than a bit of CSS to render, say, an asterisk. In general, though, you are right.

Comment: no, fair enough - i did say to use javascript, but the work around is server side scripting.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted CSS can do this but it is not fully supported and it's also not the right way to approach this problem. If it's absolutely crucial for the "required" text to appear, then you must add it in the HTML. Javascript is a suitable solution to some extent but only if you can't edit the source code. Whilst content can be generated using JS, it's obviously only going to appear to people with JavaScript enabled, and it adds to the complexity of maintenance. When someone lokos at the page in five years' time to make a code change, they are initially going to wonder where the "required" text comes from.

One other option which would be fairly quick and quite neat would be to give the span a background image of an asterisk and include a key above the form:

```
* required field
```

Comment: I like the part "When someone looks at the page in five years' time to make a code change" - thanks, didn't think of that angle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be looking at JavaScript. Adding content to tags with specific classes/ID is one thing JavaScript is used for. There are many libraries to speed up development time - jQuery, Prototype, Dojo and MooTools.

Comment: Thanks Extrakun, I should have mentioned I wanted to avoid JavaScript for this. Updated the question.

Comment: I don't think there's any other client-side solution besides JavaScript. You may then want to look at server-side programming which allows you to use templates and some simple programming to duplicate content.

Answer (score 1):

You really should add this text in the HTML. The other solutions aren’t accessible — non-sighted users (for example) wouldn’t be aware that the field is required.